# Kettle: How to insert the a specific date string from csv file to date field of a table

Tags: kettle

I'm using Kettle to import data from csv file to oracle database.
Now I face a date string in the csv file as below:

> 01-SEP-18 11.47.18.032000 AM ASIA/SHANGHAI

And the corresponding field type of the table is Date or Timestamp.

How could I use Kettle to handle this？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a time format with time zone :

In the `CSV Input` step select the date format to be `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS XXX`.

If it does not work (maybe it does not undestand AM/PM) , read the date as a **String** in `CSV Input` step. Then use a `Select value` to change the type from String to **Date** in the `Meta-Data` tab. You have plenty of option and selecting the one you need may request some trials.

If it still does not work (because it does not understand ASIA/Shangai or because it changes), then read the String in a `Javascript` step in where you can use the `str2date` function [open the `Transform function` / `Date function`, right click on the `st2date(var,var,var,var)` and select `Sample` to get the function description].

If it still does not work, then use the `Javascript` step to parse the string and compute the correct result. Quite frankly, you will probably not need to use this last resort.

Comment: Thanks, the JS is not convient to convert the date String. Now I'm trying to use the UserDefinedJavaClass to convert it.